# Image sizing issues (not fitting proportionally)

Tags: background-image, image-scaling, report-designer

I created a 8.5x11.0 inches image @ a 300dpi setting in photoshop.
When i go to use this as a background image in report designer the image looks hugeee.
It's not fitting within the 8.5x11.0 page. 
Is there a way to resize this image correctly so that it will fit correctly within a 8.5x11.0 letter size page?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

with the information you gave, i believe your problem is problably in the group Size/dpi

You saved an image of size 8,5 x 11 inches @ 300 Dpi (dots per inch) that calculates to aproximately an image of 2550 x 3300 pixels.

Now if your "report designer" software looks only at the size in pixels and assumes a dpi value diferent then the one you used, say for example 72 dpi, your 2550 x 3300 pixels image would actually be something like 45,8 x 35.4 inches.

So, my advice is, find out what are the characteristics your solftware is especting, aparently it is not 300dpi.

If you can´t find the information, try commonly used dpis like 72dpi or 150dpi.